# Setting the value of a variable in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to set the value of a patch's variable to be the same as that of one of its neighbours. What'd I'd like is something along the lines of:

```
ask patches[

    let trader max-one-of neighbors [payoff]
    set strategy [strategy of trader]

]
```

in order to set the strategy of each patch to be the same as the strategy of its neighbour that has the highest payoff. The above doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. You just didn't have the right syntax for `of`. The [dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) shows the proper placement of square brackets.

So, this should work:

```
ask patches [
  let trader max-one-of neighbors [payoff]
  set strategy [strategy] of trader
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections on your code:

1- you can not name in the same way a turtle-own and a patch-own, so i left 
`strategy` as turtle-own and `pstrategy` as patch-own

2- `neighbors` returns an agentset containing the 8 surrounding patches, and not the turtles on them, so, in order to obtain the turtles on surrounding patches  you should use `max-one-of turtles-on neighbors [payoff]` instead of `max-one-of neighbors [payoff]`

Here's how i would do it:

```
ask patches[
  ask max-one-of turtles-on neighbors [payoff] [
    set pstrategy strategy
  ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think any turtles are involved...? I don't think that's implied by the question. Even setting that aside, this code is still incorrect. The turtle will set the `pstrategy` variable of the patch it is standing on, not the calling patch.